# Как посчитать высоту первых n элементов списка?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как посчитать высоту первых n элементов(блоков) списка с помощью js/jquery?

Comment: Вы бы хоть какую-то свою попытку показали.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант на jQuery

```
var heigthList = [];

$('query').slice(0, 15).each(function(i) {
    heigthList.push($(this).height());
});
```

Вариант на Vanilla JS

```
var heigthList = [];
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('query')

Array.prototype.slice.call(elements, 0, 15).forEach(function(element) {
    heigthList.push(element.offsetHeight);
})
```